# Facebook like button in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, button, facebook-like

Is possible to add facebook like button to my ios app? I also read about own like buttons, which are connected to some facebook app.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific about what you want to do? Are you trying to style a UIButton to look like the common 'like' button? Or are you trying to drag/drop something in your NIB in xcode? Are you also asking how to hook that button up to a Facebook API? If so, I would clarify what you're looking for, exactly.

Comment: If you want a Facebook-like button, capture the image you want and use it to create a custom button.  If you want a Facebook Like button, study up on the Facebook API.

Comment: Thank you for reply, so I have a facebook fan page and I want to have a like button in my app, which will be connected to facebook api.

Any solution please? :-)